# Yes/no confirmation buttons on a slide-out panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have the following js code and am wondering how I can make it clean. It works fine but there are few repetitions. Is there a way to make it more clean?

```
$('.js-decline-button').click(function() {  
    $('.js-confirmation').show().stop(true).animate({ left : '0' }, 500);
});

$('.js-confirmation-yes').click(function() {
    $('.js-confirmation').stop(true).animate({ left : '-100%' }, 500);
    $('.container').delay( 500 ).fadeOut( 200 ).hide(200);
});

$('.js-confirmation-no').click(function() {
    $('.js-confirmation').stop(true).animate({ left : '-100%' }, 500);
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvsw7n85/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a couple of named functions:

```
var hideConfirmationMessage,
    showConfirmationMessage;

hideConfirmationMessage = function () {
    $('.js-confirmation').stop(true).animate({ left : '-100%' }, 500);
};

showConfirmationMessage = function() {  
   $('.js-confirmation').show().stop(true).animate({ left : '0' }, 500);
};
```

Then your event handler attachment becomes much simpler:

```
$('.js-confirmation-yes').click(function() {
    hideConfirmationMessage();
    $('.container').delay(500).fadeOut(200).hide(200);
});

$('.js-confirmation-no').click(hideConfirmationMessage);
$('.js-decline-button').click(showConfirmationMessage);
```

I'm not sure if that's "cleaner" to you but I think it's easier to read and doesn't repeat itself.